# Best way to achieve C break or Python pass in a SQL case expression?

Tags: sql, database, case

Given a SQL CASE expression with nested CASE expressions, I'm looking for the best way to emulate a C break or Python pass within a nested CASE expression so I can evaluate the rest of the outer WHEN choices.

For example, imagine

```
select CASE 
         WHEN C1 THEN CASE
                      WHEN CA THEN 100
                      WHEN CB THEN 200
                     -- implied ELSE NULL
                     END
         WHEN C2 THEN CASE
                      WHEN CC THEN 300
                      WHEN CD THEN 400
                      ELSE 500
                     END
         WHEN C3 THEN CASE
                      WHEN CE THEN 600
                     END
         WHEN C4
... etc
```

assume that conditions C1 and C3 are both true, C2 and C4 are false.
also assume that CA and CB are false, CE is true.

The inner case for C1, takes the implied ELSE NULL.  I'd like to functionally be able to say ELSE BREAK and allow C2, C3, etc to be evaluated as part of the outer case. The desired result is 600.

The best way I've found is to replace the outer case with a COALESCE of all the inner cases.

such as

```
COALESCE(
           CASE C1 THEN
           CASE
                WHEN CA THEN 100
                WHEN CB THEN 200
           END
           END
           ,
           CASE C2 THEN
           CASE
                WHEN CC THEN 300
                WHEN CD THEN 400
                ELSE 500
           END
           END
           ,
           CASE C3 THEN
           CASE
                WHEN CE THEN 600
           END
           END
          ,
... etc   )
```

Anyone have other ideas?  With several levels of CASE, the source code blows up in size which makes it harder to maintain.

I'm using standard SQL 2008, no extensions as one might find in T/SQL or SQL/PLUS etc.

Maybe you have a way to format my solution to make it most readable?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In sql the best thing to do is use a table and a join, so in your example create a lookup table like this (row column is just so I can reference later)

```
 Row C1  C2  C3  CA  CB  CC CD CE Value
 1   T   F   F   T   F   F  F  F  100
 2   T   F   F   F   T   F  F  F  200
 3   F   T   F   F   T   F  F  F  300
 4   F   T   F   F   F   F  T  F  400
 5   F   T   F   T   F   T  F  T  500
 6   F   F   T   F   F   F  F  T  600
 ....
```

Then your sql statement will look like this

```
 SELECT l.[value]
 FROM table t
 JOIN lookup l ON (t.C1 = l.C1 AND t.C2 = l.C2 AND t.C3 = l.C3)
              AND (t.CA = l.CA 
                OR t.CB = l.CB 
                OR t.CC = l.CC 
                OR t.CD = l.CD
                OR t.CE = l.CE)
```

I believe this is the logic you need for your inner and your outer.

Notice row 5 because the last 5 are ORed in the join this will allow the lookup to act as the ELSE in your inner cases.

You could just have all ands in the join and a "complete" lookup table -- this might be simpler to debug and work with.

Comment: I simplified the problem when I asked the original question. In the actual problem I'm solving, the values in the WHEN clauses are expressions which reference 1 or more additional columns so a join to a second table doesn't work for me. I can see how the join pattern you suggest would be really useful in other situations. thanks.

Comment: @GaryGilbert - Joins can include expressions, this technique might still work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
select CASE 
         WHEN C1 AND CA THEN 100
         WHEN C1 AND CB THEN 200
                     --- simulated BREAK
         WHEN C2 THEN CASE
                      WHEN CC THEN 300
                      WHEN CD THEN 400
                      ELSE 500
                     END
         WHEN C3 AND CE THEN 600
                     --- simulated BREAK
         WHEN C4
... etc
```

Comment: Flattening out the embedded case expr with only an outer case works sometimes. I think that it might make the eventual query difficult to maintain. Comments and indentation might help. The problem I'm addressing has about a dozen outer case WHEN clauses, of which many have inner cases with 5 to 8 WHEN clauses.  Flattening it to a single case means that there might be 60 WHEN clauses, many of which repeat the inner WHEN expressions.  The problem would get worse if the CASE expression were nested more than 2 deep. They joys of a declarative non-programmatic language. :)

Comment: @GaryGilbert: yes, for complex, nested CASEs, Hogan's approach seems more appropriate. I would use that, too.